# windows 7 копировал систему на SSD пропало восстановление системы

Tags: windows, windows-7, ssd

Нетбук hp dm1, сделал ему апгрейд, заменил hdd на ssd скопировал диск С: акронисом
Сразу не загрузился, Починил загрузчик с помощью bootrec и загрузился. 
На самом деле не такой и большой прирост как я ожидал, думал все залетает. 
Буквально быстрее работать стал ну так на мой взгляд, процентов на 20. Не больше. Я то думал, будет мгновенный старт... вобщем размечтался.

Но возникла другая проблема, на старом диске система работает и присутствует возможность восстановления системы. На новом, какой то глюк. появился в настройках восстановления 3й диск, пишет что удален, это видимо система как то запомнила, что есть старый диск. а вот для новых дисков, не дает прописать квоты под восстановление. вываливается в ошибку. скрины загружу чуть позже

[image: 3 диска]

[image: не дает создать квоту восстановления]
[image: ошибка]

ыыв

Comment: То, что у Вас не стало "так быстро, как казалось должно быть" - обычное дело. Характеристики ни одного, ни другого диска Вы не предоставили. Восстановление ОС не работает, так как Вы не перенесли раздел для восстановления. В любом случае, самое правильное решение - поставить систему по новому.

Кстати, один раз видел подобный перенос, когда не до конца перенесли  система стартовала с ссд, но грузилась с обычного. И конечно, прирост был маленький.

Comment: я не настолько глуп чтобы не понять что система грузится именно с ссд а не с отключенного который вообще вынут hdd и лежит в коробке) ssd kingston a400 120 gb

Comment: нетбук слабенький 1.2 ггц  2 ядра, 2 гига, диск был 250гб, 5400 сеагейт 
сейчас кингстон который заявлен до 500мб в сек чтение.

Comment: имею ввиду обычный магнитный диск хрустящий при работе и загрузке системы...

Answer (score 2):

по поиску решения с ошибкой 0x8007007b наткнулся на следующие статьи

Вобщем частично помогла статья с офф сайта 
https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0/2b64db1f-a653-4594-b387-9156bc2f00c4?tab=AllReplies#tabs

а также эта статья 
http://9871443.ru/statii/-0x8007007b.html

что я сделал, проверил службы, связанные с теневым копированием, отключил - включил, прямо как стандартный совет от компьютерщиков)

потом пошел в администрирование - конфиг системы, службы  и автозагрузка - отключил все что не содержит в названии microsoft 
перезагрузился, потом зашел снова в восстановление - отключил на всех дисках с ошибками но все равно отключилось. ИИИИ хоп, диск 3й пропал, потом восстановление включил и все заработало...

службы и программы из автозагрузки, что отключал, включил снова.

точка восстановления создается, проблема решена

Comment: побежал делать копию акронисом на всякий случай)